# Using an icon from Windows DLL in autorun.inf

Tags: windows, autorun

I want to set an icon for my removable drive as an icon from a built-in Windows DLL using autorun.inf. Since [Wikipedia's page on Autorun.inf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf#.5Bautorun.5D) shows that an icon can be taken from a DLL and used with an index, I would think the following would work (#54 of imageres.dll is the full recycling bin icon):

```
[autorun]
label=USB Drive
icon=%WINDIR%\System32\imageres.dll,54
```

But it does not. The icon shows up as the default "icon not found" icon when I remove and plug the device in again. Even if I use the absolute path for my system `C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll,54`, it doesn't work. Can this be done at all, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was completely wrong, you can use %WINDIR%
I tried regenerating the issue and I was able to us windir and dll file index. the icon you're trying to use did not show for some reason. but I was able to use icons from shell32.dll, I tried multiple indexes and it seems to work.

[image]

I think the problem have to do with the icon it self or something with windows.
I can confirm that you're inf file have the correct structure.

try using another icon and see what happens, [Windows Icons: Full list with details, locations & images](https://diymediahome.org/windows-icons-reference-list-with-details-locations-images/)

Comment: "Even if I use the absolute path for my system `C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll,54`, it doesn't work."

Comment: I apologize, I had my facts mixed and presented an untrue information. I updated my answer.

Comment: That's interesting. shell32.dll works for me also, whereas imageres.dll does not. Weird, but luckily the icon I want is present in both.

Answer (score 5):

Try to extract the .ico using ["Resource Hacker"](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/), put the .ico onto the drive and use the `icon=` in autorun.inf to point to that instead.

Using Resource Hacker should be straightforward enough to do this!

[image: Resource Hacker]

Comment: Or this utility to extract images...http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/resources_extract.html

Comment: The idea is that the icon corresponds to the operating system's default icon set, since icons in system DLLs change between versions.

Comment: @SamM It makes sense. I don't have a source on this but it might be a "security feature" that it's not allowed to point to system files in autorun.inf files. Things have been owned with autorun.inf in the past. EDIT: Actually people have used icons from System32 with success so I don't know what to say as to why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Moab Well that extracts everything like a big vacuum, though.

Comment: @sinni800 do you have a link for the successful attempts at using System32 icons?

Comment: @sinni800 you can choose what to extract.

Comment: @SamM http://superuser.com/questions/1032272/using-an-icon-from-windows-dll-in-autorun-inf/1032333 Actually right here